# Using Timeago jQuery plugin with Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm attempting to integrate the timeago jQuery plugin with a custom wordpress theme build to display the time a post was published.

As the theme is built using HTML5, timeago requires the inserted code to look a little like this:

```
<time class="timeago" datetime="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z"></time>
```

Obviously, simply using `<?php the_time() ?>`doesn't work, as the time has to be formatted as above.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested in what the solution to this turned out to be:

I actually dropped the plugin and added this to my functions.php file in Wordpress,

```
function time_ago( $type = 'post' ) {
$d = 'comment' == $type ? 'get_comment_time' : 'get_post_time';
return human_time_diff($d('U'), current_time('timestamp')) . " " . __('ago');
```

}

That does the trick! Okay, it doesn't update in real time but with each page refresh is good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but i've just find the solution so for those still interested...

`<time class="timeago" datetime="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z"></time>`

Becomes in your WP theme

`<time class="timeago" datetime="<?php echo get_the_date('Y-m-d\TH:i\Z'); ?>"></time>`

Thomas